# Read file and print in specific format. C++

Tags: c++

I have to write a program in C++ and I haven't used this laugauge before.

I know how to write it in Java or C#, but I should write it in C++!

The code should read a text file (I do this step) and then print the output in a specific format using the array (I don't now how to do this step)

For example:
The file has the following:

```
Task          distribution             duration              dependence
A              Normal                  2,10                     -
B              UNIF                    2,7                      A
```

The code will print the following:

The task A is a normal distribution and it is duration between 2 and 10. It doesn't depend on any task. Task B is unif distribution, etc.

---

I want to mention that it is not a homework or an assignment to be submitted to the teacher, but I work in a research project (something extra to learn something new before leaving the University) and they ask us to use C++ which I found to be difficult to learn (I have other courses with grades which I should consider rather than doing the research).

---

I write the code in C# and I searched for utilities to convert from C# to C++, but it doesn't work!

http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_CPlusPlus_CSharp_Edition.html

This is my code in C# and it works correctly.

```
class Program
{
    static List<string []> allTasks = new List<string []>();
    static List<TaskInfo> Tasks = new List<TaskInfo>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        string[] info = null;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\7bah Jno0ney\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Example1_C++\\Tasks.txt");
        string fLine = sr.ReadLine();
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.Replace("\r", "");
            info = line.Split(' ');
            allTasks.Add(info);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < allTasks.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < allTasks[i].Length; j++)
            {
                allTasks[i][j] = allTasks[i][j].Replace("\r", "");
                allTasks[i][j] = allTasks[i][j].Replace("   ", "");
            }
            TaskInfo task = new TaskInfo(allTasks[i][0], allTasks[i][1], allTasks[i][2], allTasks[i][3]);
            Tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You have " + Tasks.Count + " Tasks.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < Tasks.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Tasks[i].getTaskDep() == null || Tasks[i].getTaskDep() == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The first task in the project is the task " + Tasks[i].getTaskName() +". " +
                    "The task distribution is " + Tasks[i].getTaskDis() + " and its duration is " + Tasks[i].getTaskDur() + "." + " Finally, it doesn't has any dependence");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                string name = Tasks[i].getTaskName();
                string dep = Tasks[i].getTaskDep();
                if(dep.Contains(","))
                {
                    string[] depends = dep.Split(',');
                    Console.Write("Task " + Tasks[i].getTaskName() + " has " + Tasks[i].getTaskDis() + 
                        " distribution and its duration is " + Tasks[i].getTaskDur() + ". ");
                    Console.Write("This task depends on " + depends.Length + " tasks.");
                    for (int d = 0; d < depends.Length; d++)
                    {
                        int num = d + 1;
                        Console.Write(" The " + num + " depended task is " + depends[d] + ". ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (TaskInfo ti in Tasks)
                    {
                        if((ti.getTaskName() == name) && (ti.getTaskDep() == dep)){
                            Console.WriteLine("This Task is the " + i + 
                                " task and its distribution is " + Tasks[i].getTaskDis() + 
                                ". It is duration is " + Tasks[i].getTaskDur() +
                                " and it depends on the task " + ti.getTaskDep());
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

What are some utilities or programs to help to converting the code?

Comment: you can post your c# code and then someone can help you convert it to c++

Comment: By saying "i do this step" do you mean you have code written to do this? If so can you include that code in your question? P.S. Please remove the "specific" tag, it has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ probably what you should be looking at is using a file stream (`std::ifstream` most likely) for the reading, and the standard output stream (`std::cout`) for writing. Given the lack of detail, the best I can tell you after that is to go read up on C++ file streams and stream formatting. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0240__File-Stream/Catalog0240__File-Stream.htm) I found online for file streams, and [here's one for stream formatting](http://www.deitel.com/articles/cplusplus_tutorials/20060218/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using one of two routes, C++ streams or `printf` of C fame.

For C++ streams, have a look at the [I/O Manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) library, especially these functions:
  `setw`
  `setprecision`
  `left`
  `right`

For the `printf` technique, look at the [format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/):
  `%d`
  `%c`
  `%s`

I highly recommend using spaces instead of tabs.  There is no standard tab size for consoles.

If you are dealing with a GUI, I recommend either using a table widget or using font metrics to get accurate alignment.  You could cheat and use a fixed pitch font, but the correct and laborious method is to calculate the width of each character, then determine the spacing necessary.  Or just put the text a fixed horizontal location.